# SQL Null statement not working MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I'm not really sure what is going on here but in my database I have a table that has 1000 records and 36 of them have [workername] empty. I was trying to run this SQL to select the unassigned, empty [workername] records to assign but nothing populates when I put the code in query design and view mode. I genuinely have no idea why this is not working.

```
strSQL = "SELECT IntakeID, 
                 caseid, 
                 [Program], 
                 [language] 
          FROM Intake 
          WHERE workername Is Null"
     Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Check whether the field contains an empty string: `WHERE Len(workername) = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code..Here first it will replace null value to `''` using `Nz` and if not null it will trim the value to make sure there is no space and check  is it equal to `''` means empty..hope it will help

```
"SELECT IntakeID, 
caseid, 
[Program], 
[language] 
FROM
Intake WHERE  LTRIM(RTRIM(Nz(workername, ''))) = ''"
```

Comment: EVERYONE should literally up vote this!!! I have looked EVERYWHERE for this issue and this was the only one that worked!

Answer (score 0):

That query looks valid, so I would question whether the column is actually null.

You could try the following to find out for sure

```
SELECT 
    IntakeID, 
    caseid, 
    [Program], 
    [language] ,
    ISNULL(workername)
FROM Intake 
  ORDER BY ISNULL(workername) ASC
```

Comment: For some odd reason an `Expr1:IsNull([workername])` but workername is literally in the drop down as an option and the code worked for the 900+ other records so it's very odd.

Comment: Don't you just love Access :)